# How to Tell if Network Traffic is Encrypted

Tags: networking, internet, encryption, ssl

I'm using a program called LottaNZB to connect to a Usenet server. I've connected to the SSL port, but I'd like to check it's actually connected. How can this be done?

I've used Wireshark, but I can't see any sign the traffic is encrypted.

Comment: If it looks like it isn't encrypted in wireshark, then it isn't.  If it is, then wireshark will say that it is encrypted and be unable to show the contents.

Comment: I'm not sure how to tell if the traffic is encrypted though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encrypted traffic you can see with some traffic analyzer. 
Wireshark is one good.
Instal them with command
`sudo apt-get install wireshark`

Run it with `sudo wireshark`
Pick the net interface and click start.
In filter type:

```
ip.addr == ip_address_of_usenet_server
```

In field below you will see only communication between your client and server.
If traffic is encrypted you will see tlsv1 packets or some another encryption and ssl layer traffic packets. If traffic is not encrypted ssl layer traffic will missing